# RequestScope-Bean init after apply request

Tags: spring, jsf, lifecycle

i've an Requestscoped Bean which reads the state of an conversation scoped bean in it's @postconstruct mehod. But it is created before the request is applied to the conversation scoped bean, so the data is one request behind. How can i init the request-scoped bean later?

Comment: You can try putting your logic on getter method in your request bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `<f:event type="preRenderView">`. Put this somewhere in top of the view (the exact location is actually irrelevant, but somewhere in top of view is most self-documenting):

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}" />
```

The method can just look like this, don't forget to remove the `@PostConstruct`.

```
public void init() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: so there is no straight solution for this?